# how to add an 'add product' button on account page

Tags: lightning, custom-button, person-accounts

I'm very new to salesforce, and my scenario is that I enabled the **person account** in salesforce, and I don't want to use opportunities; I want to relate the product from the opportunity to the account instead. I have tried to create a lookup relationship from opportunity product to account, but when I go to the account page on the related list, I see the opportunity product, but there is no add product button. I have also tried to do the same with Product 2, but it doesn't seem to match my requirements (Opportunity Product is a better idea). Please help me, I really need this.

[image]

Comment: Opportunities are a cornerstone of Salesforce. As you say, you are new to Salesforce. As an experienced Salesforce developer, I tell you: first follow the rules. And when you have enough experience, you can decide to deviate from them if you really need to.

Comment: As @SanderdeJong has mentioned you are best trying to stay with the standard at first until you understand why it is done like this by salesforce. with opportunity you want to group product per sales(opportunity) and can then display a consolidated view on the account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is not how to add a button but how to add a relation between products and accounts.

The first option is to use opportunities and the opportunity products as this supports your sales process.

however if you are only interested in keeping track of which products are used by an account together with additional data like quantity or purchase date you would could create your own [junction object](https://www.salesforceben.com/what-is-a-junction-object-in-salesforce/).

for this you would need to create a new AccountProduct object that has a [master detail or lookup](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/data_modeling/object_relationships) to both account and product2 together with fields for other relevant data that you want to store on the products related to your account.

after creating this object you can add the related list on your account page where you will see the add button available